# new to android - not able to access global variable in protected static method

Tags: java, android

here is my code:

```
protected static Bitmap scaleImage() { 
Bitmap nad =    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

return nad;
}
```

"path" is a global variable, and it gives me an error stating: cannot make a static reference to a non-static field path... may be this is happening because path is a string, and not a static.. but how else can I access other variables in here? I tried looking through the documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: There is nothing such as global variable in Android, I'm afraid. Please post the whole class. You should become familiar with basic OOP concepts, and the static and instance variables of a class.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `path` is declared something like this inside your class:

```
String path;
```

This means that it's an *instance variable*, which belongs to a specific copy of your class. `scaleImage()` doesn't belong to any particular copy, and so you can't use `path` because the system would have no way of knowing which copy you meant.

This method should probably take `path` as a parameter instead of having it hardcoded, or it shouldn't be `static` and should be called on a particular instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're on the right track. `path` must be `static`. It's not enough that it's a member variable in the class - class level variables aren't automatically `static` (that'd be a problem).

Global variables don't exist in Java, so I guess you're talking about a variable declared on class level. (The variable is inside the class, the class is inside a package, which can be inside other packages - so it's far from being "global.")

Comment: I need to access an bitmap object from class1 into class2, so it thought this would be the way, do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: We do have other suggestions. ;-) But please post more code so we're all sure what we're talking about.

Comment: @fishman - your question is getting downvoted because you're not showing your work and it's clear you don't understand. BUT people will help you here if you show more effort and more code.